# Rails: Validate Unique Pairs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model

I have a model called Users. I want two Users to be associated with my Conversation model, but I want the pairs of users (User1, User2) to be unique. For example, If user1 is 5 and user2 is 6, there cannot be a pair where user1 is 6 and user2 is 5.

I already made sure the two users are not the same/there are no User1 and User2 combinations are identical

```
validates :user1_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user2_id}
```

but How do do I make sure that if there is a conversation with User1 and User2, there cannot be a convo with User2 and User1? Also, how can I also make sure User1 and User2 are not the same? (ie, Invalid if User1 is 6 and User2 is also 6)

Comment: @Gerry I edited the post so it's not a duplicate!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a [custom validation method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods):

```
validate :validate_users_are_unique

private

def validate_users_are_unique
  if self.class.where(user1_id: user1_id, user2_id: user2_id)
               .or(self.class.where(user1_id: user2_id, user2_id: user1_id))
               .exists?
    errors.add(:base, 'User 1 and User 2 combination exists!')
  end
end
```

Another option might be to sort the user ids and to ensure that `user1_id` is always the smaller of the two. Then the default Rails' uniqueness validation can be used. And the uniqueness can be ensured at the database level by adding a unique index:

```
# in the model
before_validation :sort_user_ids
validates :user1_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user2_id }

private

def sort_user_ids
  self.user1_id, self.user2_id = [user1_id, user2_id].sort
end

# in a migration
add_index :table_name, [:user1_id, :user2_id], unique: true
```

Comment: Keep in mind that validations do not actually guarantee database integrity. Your Rails validations may pass, but you could still end up with invalid entries in your database. The only way to ensure true consistency is through database-level constraints, foreign keys and unique indexes.

Comment: @chickenburgers That is correct for all kinds of uniques validators within an application. But I am not sure if it is even possible to configure a unique index for this kind of constraint. Perhaps it might be worth it to always sort the user ids (`user1_id` to be always the smaller id and `user2_id` always the bigger). Then a default Rails' unique validation with a unique database index would work. If this is possible depends on if the sorting of `user1` and `user2` has some meaning.

Comment: @spickermann Where you say "in a validation," I think you mean, "in a migration."